# EmailMessage Validation Rule fired twice

Tags: email, validation, validation-rule, order-of-execution

This issue has been repeatable in a plain Sandbox and Developer Edition Org:

**Setup:** One EmailMessage validation rule. No workflows, flows, processes or triggers or Rollup fields are implemented.

**Issue:** When sending an E-Mail from the Chatter publisher, we can observe from the logs that at the beginning of the transaction the EmailMessage is validated with a validation rule. At the end of the transaction, the EmailMessage is validated again.

When sending an E-Mail with the classic "Send Email" functionality, the EmailMessage is validated only once.

**Log file for sending the email over classic send email functionality:** http://pastebin.com/raw/7bwEzQbT

**Log file for sending the email over publisher functionality:**
http://pastebin.com/raw/HJQyVSXs

**Question:** Why is the EMailMessage validated twice when sent from the publisher? When looking at the log files some additional workflows are fired when using the publisher. Why is that so and is that the reason the validation is fired twice? From my understanding a custom validation is only executed once after the "before" triggers.

Comment: Is a trigger used that calls a class to send the Email in some way as part of outbound web services or something along those lines? Is this Web to Case, Email to Case or simply Cases? Try increasing the settings on your debug logs to more detail to see what else may be firing.

Comment: All that aside, does it matter if validations fire once or twice? The net effect should be the same.

Comment: I have learned that the Email is only validated twice when I send an email from the publisher/Chatter functionality. Using the classic "Send Email function" the Email is only validated once. I have attached logs, could you please have a look at it?
@sfdcfox: It matters for two reasons: (Maybe most importantly) I would like to get a deep understanding about how and when actions are performed within a transaction. Further, we had a setup where a workflow modified a case in a way that made the email validation fail although from my understanding the validation should not have been performed.